# TBXML textForElement issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, html-parsing, tbxml

I'm trying to parser an HTML with the TBXML library for iOS and I want to obtain the "more text" value for this piece of HTML:

```
<div> 
 <a href="/url/1">
   <strong>value</strong>
 </a>
 more text
</div>
```

I have used this code, but it does not seems to work:

```
//Assume that "div" is a TBXMLElement* for this div 
NSString* content = [TBXML textForElement:div];
//Returns @"" when the value @"more text" is expected...
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have modified the TBXML Library and I have resolved the problem...If someone has the same issue, try this:

1) Create an attribute  in the file TBXML.h for TBXMLElement with name NSString* afterText.

2) Search this code in the file TBXML.m and comment it:

```
// if parent element has children clear text
                if (parentXMLElement && parentXMLElement->firstChild)
                    parentXMLElement->text = 0;
```

3) Write this code before the code of the step 1:

```
if (parentXMLElement && parentXMLElement->firstChild){

            //if the next string does not content...
            const char * parentNametag =  [[TBXML elementName:parentXMLElement] UTF8String];
            char * finalTag =  (char *)malloc(sizeof("</")+sizeof(parentNametag)+sizeof(">"));
            strcpy(finalTag,"</");
            strcat(finalTag,parentNametag);
            strcat(finalTag,">");

            char * elementTextStart = elementStart;//parentXMLElement->text;
            char * elementTextEnd = elementTextStart;

            elementTextEnd = strstr(elementStart,finalTag);

            if(elementTextEnd != NULL){
                long textLength = strlen(elementTextStart) - strlen(elementTextEnd) ;
                if (textLength > 0){
                    afterTextStart = (char *)malloc(textLength*sizeof(char));
                    memcpy(afterTextStart, elementTextStart,(textLength*sizeof(char)));
                    parentXMLElement->afterText = afterTextStart;
                }
            }

        }
```

Now the attribute "after text" contains *"more text"*.

It's not an orthodox solution but it's works for me.

Comment: I have did only comment the code which you mentioned in step 2 and it works me too. Thanks.